# Digitizing map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am relatively new to QGIS and using its version 1.8.0 on Windows Vista.
Problem:

1. I have to digitise an aerial map and then extract the coordinates.
2. I have absolutely no idea how to start

Comment: What information do you hope to digitize from the aerial map?  What format is the aerial map in?

Comment: HI aaron,I hope to extract coordinates of buildings in a city. the aerial map is from google earth.

Comment: There is another problem, if you want to digitize from aerial photographs, everything will be distorted since this kind of material does no have a constant scale. On the other hand if you are usin already orthorectified material you can do it without a problem, since this kinf of material comes already with a Coordinate system.

Answer (score 5):

If you have absolutely no idea how to start you should definitely read some tutorials first. The purpose of this site is to help you with GIS problems and **not** to teach you how to work with GIS-software! IMHO this requires to take ether a professional course or a lot of spare time for reading/practice. 
Here are some tutorials to get you started.

For basic and advanced tutorials:
[http://gistutor.com/quantum-gis.html](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/)

For applied tutorials including digitalization:
http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/

Click through the tutorials and if you still stumble upon any problems during a specific problem than post the details of your problem in a new question (mentioning the software you used).